# managing two copies of data

Tags: django, database-design

I have a cron process that periodically reads several public web sites and stores the data in a database. The collected data are then published on my website.

These data are represented by a set of related models in django.

I need to have two sets of data: one that is published and the other one that was just collected by the cron process. After the latter is manually reviewed for accuracy I need to make it public and remove the set that was public before.

I see two ways to do it:

1. have each model to include a flag indicating whether it is public or not.
2. have two separate databases.

each has its own drawbacks and advantages.

Has anyone implemented something similar before? Any advice on how to do it elegantly?

Comment: When you say 2 databases, don't you mean 2 tables? Within a single schema you can have multiple tables and have independent accounts work on those tables (with access to tables on a per-user level).

Comment: I mean two separate databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commonly, all applications have data that is private for someone and public for others. For example, on stackoverflow, you can read your e-mail address but I can't read your e-mail. This don't means that stackoverflow has a database for each user.

Basically you have two ways to protect your data:

1. application restricts access to data.
2. database restricts access to data (with users, views and grands)

You can implement applicacion security (1) or application + database security (1+2).

One database may be enough if your security design is correct but perhaps you collect massive data (several terabytes) and you want to split database load over two servers. Really, this question has a lot of parameters.

Whell, this is a synthesis exercice.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am not talking about authorisation. I want to read data from somewhere, check if it is correct, and swap whatever old data I have with the new one.

Comment: Ok, you can versioning data and show only the newest data and delete old data when you want.

Comment: the reason why I asked this question is because I wanted to know how people implemented versioning, given that my particular case is a subset of the versioning problem because I do not want to maintain history. Just the last seen data and the "current" ones.

Comment: oh. Then you can add a boolean attribute to primary key named thisIsLastVersion ;) This will force to have uniquely two versions of each fact.